# Can you help me with a logic to solve this puzzle?

Tags: sudoku

[image]

I know the concept of pairing and removed pairs but what other concepts should I use to solve this?

Comment: You could try guessing and check if it works in your mind, like when there are two possibilities, like in the bottom right square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only one place to put

> a 6 in column 1

followed by the

> 6 in row 6

Comment: Could you add a rationale?

Comment: @030 Is it not obvious? There is only one cell in the first column that still contains a small 6.