# What patterns could be applied in order to solve a Sudoku?

Tags: pattern, sudoku

[image]

Related to [this Q&A](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/89922/63214). I am looking for a pattern that could be applied in order to solve this Sudoku.

The current patterns that I apply:

- Ensure that every digit appears once in every block
- Ensure that there is a unique sequence from 1 to 9.

Now I am blocked as the block top right could contain a 8 and a 5, but I cannot rationalize where the 8 and where the 5 should be placed. What pattern am I missing?

As encouraged by @legorhin I tried to come up with possible solutions for the Sudoku cells.

[image]

Comment: solve other parts of the puzzle then come back to it later

Comment: Why have you got a 7 in r7c2? What about r9c3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I saw was:

> In the middle column, the 6 has to be on the top row, because the other two rows already contain a 6.

The second thing I saw:

> The cell at R7C2 can only be a 3 because all other numbers are in a shared row/column/sector.
>  This makes R8C6 a 3 also, which makes R2C5 a 3.  I think after that it gets easier.

Answer (score 2):

> Look at the bottom middle block. The 6's in row 6 column 4 and row 7 column 8 mean that the $6$ in this block is on the right hand side. Using this with the 6 at r2c9 and the 6 at r6c4 mean that r1c5=6.

Also:

> The 6's at r4c3 and r7c8 collude with the 9's at r5c3 and r7c7 to means that r8c1 and r1c9 are both 6 and 9. This means the remainder of the lower left block is {1,3,8}, and therefore r7c2=3, r7c1=1 and r8c3=8.

Comment: You and I are seeing the same thing, at the same time, lol.

Answer (score 2):

My late contribution:

> The $6$ supplied by other answers could have been solved without filling in any possibles. There are three numbers $3,6,7$ missing from the centre column, and the $6$ can only go in the top cell.
>
>  Similarly there are three numbers $3,7,9$ missing from the second column, and the $3$ can only go in the cell at the top of the bottom block (yet you marked the possibilities $3,7$).
>
>  So this is one of my techniques: for any row, column or block already well populated, see where the missing ones can fit.
>
>  Allied to this, is that when you have a duplicate pair possible in any row, column or block, as you have with the $3,7$ in the centre column, you can remove all other $3$s and $7$s in that element - here leaving that lone $6$.
>
>  The same goes in the rarer  case when you spot a set of **three** numbers appearing as the only possibles in three cells.